# NoClassDefFoundError--org/apache/bcel/generic/InstructionConstants

Tags: java, xml, csv

I am trying to convert a huge .xml file into .csv file , following is the code I am using to read xml and write the file into csv.

```
public class XMLToCSVMappings {
    private static XPathFactory xPathFactory = null;
    private static DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        ReadXML();
    }

public static void ReadXML() {
        System.out.println("In ReadXML method");
            File xmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\maya\\Desktop\\AllObjects.xml");
            try {
                InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
                if (fis != null) {
                    Document xmlDoc = getDocFromXMLString(fis);
                    HashMap<String, String> propertiesKeypair = readPropertyFile();
                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\maya\\Desktop\\AllObjects.csv");
                    writer.append("Key");
                    writer.append(',');
                    writer.append("Value");
                    writer.append('\n');

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : propertiesKeypair .entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + "Xpath value is::"+ getElementValue(entry.getValue(), xmlDoc));
                    writer.append(entry.getKey());
                    writer.append(',');
                    writer.append(getElementValue(entry.getValue(), xmlDoc));
                    writer.append('\n');
                }
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                System.out.println("ResultMap Updated. CSV File is being generated...");
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}

    public static Document getDocFromXMLString(InputStream xml)
        throws Exception {
            DocumentBuilder builder;
            Document doc;
        try {
            builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(xml);
            } 
        catch (Exception exception) {
        throw exception;
        }
        finally {
        }
        return doc;
    }

    public static String getElementValue(final String xpathExpression,
        final Document doc) {
            String textValue = null;
        try {
            XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
            textValue = xpath.evaluate(xpathExpression, doc);
        }
        catch (final XPathExpressionException xpathException) {
            xpathException.printStackTrace();
    }
        return textValue;
}

    public static HashMap<String, String> readPropertyFile() {
            System.out.println("In readPropertyFile method");
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream input;
            HashMap<String, String> Propvals = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try {

            input = XMLToCSVMappings.class.getResourceAsStream("JustProperties.properties");
            System.out.println("before load");
            prop.load(input);
            System.out.println("Property File Loaded Succesfully");
            Set<String> propertyNames = prop.stringPropertyNames();
        for (String Property : propertyNames) {
            Propvals.put(Property, prop.getProperty(Property));
        }
            System.out.println("HashMap generated::" + Propvals);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return Propvals;
}
}
```

and I am seeing this error. I have added required jar files to the class path.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/bcel/generic/InstructionConstants
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: how do you build the application? are you using maven?

Comment: @kuhajeyan thanks for the reply I am using maven and I have reduced error , now only error I am seeing is null pointer exception                      `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
 at XMLToCSVMappings.readPropertyFile(XMLToCSVMappings.java:108)
 at XMLToCSVMappings.ReadXML(XMLToCSVMappings.java:44)
 at XMLToCSVMappings.main(XMLToCSVMappings.java:34) `

Comment: is this resource JustProperties.properties, available in your classpath ?

Comment: I didn't understood exactly, If you mean the source file , yes it is available

Comment: what i meant is, the error seems to be coming from this line  input = XMLToCSVMappings.class.getResourceAsStream("JustProperties.properties");

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, I was trying to add the file to class path in this way but don't know wether this way is correct --> `java -cp "/AllObjects.xml:/fileconverter/XmlConverter/src/" XMLToCSVMappings
Error: Could not find or load main class XMLToCSVMappings`

Comment: just drop the JustProperties.p‌​roperties inside main\resources

Comment: I have done that but it didn't worked